# Passing SpinnerDateModel formatted value to String

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I think my problem has a simple solution but I am new to Java programming so I wasn't able to solve it myself, I have this jSpinner that I used as time picker. What I need is to pass this jSpinner's value to a string. Please help me do this.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

This is the code of the Spinner

```
Spintimetoplay = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

SpinnerDateModel model = new SpinnerDateModel();
model.setValue(calendar.getTime());

JSpinner Spintimetoplay = new JSpinner(model);

JSpinner.DateEditor editor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(Spintimetoplay, "HH:mm");
DateFormatter formatter = (DateFormatter)editor.getTextField().getFormatter();
formatter.setAllowsInvalid(false);
formatter.setOverwriteMode(true);

Spintimetoplay.setEditor(editor);
```

Whenever I used .getValue() as some suggestions said it gives me 0 value rather than 00:00(for example).

Comment: what is the type of 'value' attribute in SpinnerDateModel ?integer or string?

Comment: then how do you expect it to return "00:00"? Integer will only store value not formatting.

Comment: i am sorry, i'm confused of your first question sir. are you asking about the model type of the spinner or the value which will accept the spinner value? thank you sir.

Comment: sorry.. ignore my question. its wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I need is to pass this jSpinner's value to a string.

So get the spinner's value (since you use a [SpinnerDateModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerDateModel.html) it will return a [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object) and use a [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to get the string you need:

```
Date value = (Date)spinTimeToPlay.getValue(); // Note code convention here
String formattedValue = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(value);
```

---

#### Off-topic

Please take a look to [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) and stick to them:

> *"Except for variables, all instance, class, and class constants are in mixed case with  a lower-case first letter. Internal words start with capital letters."*

---

#### Edit

Based on your comment:

> I got this error `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.Date`

I overlloked that you have two `Spintimetoplay` variables in your code:

```
Spintimetoplay = new javax.swing.JSpinner(); // probably a class member
...
SpinnerDateModel model = new SpinnerDateModel();
...
JSpinner Spintimetoplay = new JSpinner(model); // local variable here
```

Here you set the right `SpinnerDateModel` to a local variable instead to the right `Spintimetoplay` class member. So when you try to return the value set in this class member its model is not `SpinnerDateModel` but [SpinnerNumberModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html) and consequently it returns an integer value causing a [ClassCastException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html). You should make this changes:

```
// Spintimetoplay = new javax.swing.JSpinner(); remove this line
...
SpinnerDateModel model = new SpinnerDateModel();
...
Spintimetoplay = new JSpinner(model); // initialize your class member here
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply sir, but I got this error "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.util.Date" any suggestion how to fix this sir? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to acces the text via

```
editor.getTextField().getText()
```

is not tested though

Comment: I cannot make it work that way, but thank you so much!